# The needed libraries seem to be installed - what's causing this 'Error while loading shared libraries'?

Tags: shared-library

I have been trying to launch a game. I got this error in the terminal:

```
$ ./MoonTown.x86_64.x86 
./MoonTown.x86_64.x86: error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed `libxcursor-dev` after that, and when that didn't help, tried installing `libscb-cursor0` too, since it also showed up on an apt-cache search for libxcursor. And libxcursor1, though I think everything in it was covered by libxcursor-dev. But, the error when trying to launch this program remains the same.

So, what now?

My system is Ubuntu 18.04.

If you are motivated enough, you could download the package causing this issue here:

https://www.moonwards.com/download/

Perhaps that would allow someone to identify the problem.

Comment: The command `ldd ./MoonTown.x86_64.x86` may provide some helpful information

Comment: @steeldriver All that returned was `ldd: ./MoonTown.x86_64.: No such file or directory
` I have an older version of the game (we built it, you see) which runs from a similar export package

Comment: Try the ldd with the full name, you left off the last part, the .x86.

Comment: Oh - that was silly. Yeah, now it lists four more missing libraries in addition to the one in the error above. But I don't know how to use those names to identify what packages they are part of and go get them.

Comment: I use apt-file search filename to find the package a file belongs to (install apt-file, then run apt-file update first).  Are you sure you installed the libxcursor1 package because that should have the first missing library?

Comment: @ubfan1 No, it never installed. It says `unable to  locate package libXcursor.so.1`. The thing is, i decided to look in the usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder for the hell of it, and there it is. I'm looking right at it. I have both the .1 and the .1.0.2 versions and they are 39.2 KB and last modified on 12 dec 2017.

Comment: Alright. It turns out this package was exported with the x86 settings, and my x86_64 system didn't have these libraries for the i386 versions. I've re-exported for 64 bit and it runs fine. I eventually realized that when i entered the `ldd` command the libraries listed were all in the i386 folder and that my 64 bit system had no reason to have them.

Answer (score 2):

This was due to the settings for exporting the game from Godot having the checkbox for 64 bit unchecked. So my system looked for all libraries in the i386 directory. Once I exported the game again with that checkbox ticked, it ran fine.